# Masonry - expand after click, but keep columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to build a two column Masonry-based layout, with expanding boxes after click.

My current code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/2auahsuz/

JavaScript that expands the blocks:

```
expandBlocks: function() {
    $('.main-blocks').on('click', 'article.expand, article.collapse', function() {
        Functions.expandThis($(this));
    })
},


expandThis: function(block) {
    var scrollTo = block,
            mode;

    $('.main-blocks').off('click');

    $('article').not(block).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand').children('.desc').velocity('slideUp', {duration:100});
    });

    if(block.hasClass('expand')) {
        mode = 'slideDown';
        block.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
    } else {
        mode = 'slideUp';
        block.addClass('expand').removeClass('collapse');
    };

    block.children('.desc').not(':animated').velocity(
        mode, {
            duration: 200,
            progress: function() {
                $('.main-blocks').masonry();
            },
            complete: function() {
                Functions.masonryBlocks(scrollTo);
                Functions.expandBlocks();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

All works great, but what I want is to keep column order. I mean, when I click on a block on the left side, I want to animate only blocks below that one, not the ones on the right. Ho can I achieve that?

Comment: I know it's been a long time since the question was asked, but I'm needing the exact same solution, does anyone happen to know an answer?

Comment: Hi @MohammedAlsaedi, I haven't found a solution for this. Instead, If I recall correctly, we chose to use Freewall.js where this problem isn't present.

Comment: Thank you for your response Tomek! I will keep that in mind. I have also managed to get it to work using packery.js, which is another script by the same developers as masonry.js, and it has that feature set as 'shiftLayout' attribute. Just for reference in case anyone else is looking.